# Updating nested Primefaces elements doesn't work

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

since yesterday i can't figure this out:

I have this form in .xhtml

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="formToolbar">
    <p:growl id="messages" />
    <p:toolbar id="toolbar">
        <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
            <h:outputText value="Epimarket: occasion cars" />
            <p:separator />
        </p:toolbarGroup>
        <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
            <p:commandButton type="button" id="checkout" value="Checkout"
                onclick="PF('dlg3').show()" title="signup" icon="ui-icon-check"
                rendered="#{(not empty tableBean.droppedCars) and (loginBean.logged)}" />
            <p:commandButton type="button" id="signupLink" value="Sign up"
                onclick="PF('dlg2').show()" title="signup" icon="ui-icon-play"
                rendered="#{!loginBean.logged}" />
            <p:commandButton type="button" id="loginLink" value="Login"
                onclick="PF('dlg').show()" title="login" icon="ui-icon-script"
                rendered="#{!loginBean.logged}" />
            <p:commandButton type="button" id="logout" value="Logout"
                onclick="#{loginBean.doLogout}" title=""
                icon="ui-icon-circle-close" rendered="#{loginBean.logged}" />
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

At the first visit the user see the **Login** and **Sign up** buttons

When he click on it it pop some **dialogs**, and when those dialogs are completed he click on:

```
<p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login"
        update="growl :formToolbar:toolbar" actionListener="#{loginBean.login}"
                    oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)" />
```

*Growl2 refer to another pat of the code.

What I expect it would do is that when Submit command button is clicked it try to render again the button group contained in the #toolbar, in order to re render them.

I think this question is dummish but I can't find how to make it works.

Comment: The logout button will fail as it should be **action=="#{loginBean.doLogout}"** instead of **onclick="#{loginBean.doLogout}"**.

Comment: Yep, I changed it 30 minutes ago, but thanks for the info.
Do you know if there are any differences between using **=** or **==** ?

Comment: That was my mistake, I meant to write **=**. Have you noticed the new comment on my answer?

Comment: Yep, all is find I figured this out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the problem is in your managed bean.

Here is a simplified code sample inspired in your description:

**The View**

```
<h:form id="formToolbar">
    <p:growl id="messages" />
    <p:toolbar id="toolbar">
        <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
            <h:outputText value="Epimarket: occasion cars" />
            <p:separator />
        </p:toolbarGroup>
        <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
            <p:commandButton type="button" id="loginLink" value="Login"
                             onclick="PF('dlg').show()" title="login" icon="ui-icon-script"
                             rendered="#{!loginBean.logged}" />
            <p:commandButton id="logout" value="Logout"
                             action="#{loginBean.doLogout}" title=""
                             icon="ui-icon-circle-close" rendered="#{loginBean.logged}" update="messages,toolbar" />
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>
</h:form>

<p:dialog header="Enter Username/Password" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">  
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">  
            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />  
            <p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}" />  

            <h:outputLabel for="passwd" value="Password:" />  
            <p:password id="passwd" value="#{loginBean.password}" />  
        </h:panelGrid>  

        <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide();" 
                         update=":formToolbar:messages, :formToolbar:toolbar" action="#{loginBean.doLogin}"/>  
        <p:defaultCommand target="loginButton" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

**The Managed Bean**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private boolean logged;

    public void doLogin() {
        logged = true;
    }

    public void doLogout() {
        logged = false;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean getLogged() {
        return logged;
    }

    public void setLogged(boolean logged) {
        this.logged = logged;
    }

}
```

Comment: My LoginBean is already the same as the one you sent. It also have the managed and SessionScoped tags

I think the problem is more focused on the selection of what I need to update.

I know jquery selectors well, but I can't make thoses works

Comment: The sample code I posted is working on my development environment. See if changing the **growl** to **:formToolbar:growl** in your loginButton does any difference. By the way, what version of Primefaces are you using?

Comment: Using Primefaces 4.0. I have no problem for targeting the growl, it update as requested.

I changed radically my code and it works now... I dont really get why but I dont have time to dig this, I hate java and it's a school project :)

Thanks for your help Daniel!

My main advice if you run into this kind of problems: **:id1:id2  < absolute "selector path"**